# For a, b ∈ N, let A and B be the sets of all integer multiples of a and b. Prove that for all a,b ∈ N, a = b iff A = B.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

I am an undergraduate student. Please tell me if my proof is correct. Thanks!

**For a, b ∈ N, let A and B be the sets of all integer multiples of a and b. Prove that for all a,b ∈ N,  a = b  iff A = B.**

Assume that a and b are natural numbers. Assume also that A and B are the sets of all integer multiples of a and b.

If a = b, then ak = bk for any integer k. But ak and bk are the multiples of a and b. Therefore, all the elements of A are the same elements of B, and all the elements of B are the same of A. Thus, A = B.

In the opposite direction, if A = B, the elements of A and B are the same. The elements of A  have the form x = ak, and the elements of B have the form x = bk for any integer k. Then, ak = bk. Thus, a = b. Q.E.D.

Answer (score 2):

The first half of the proof is basically correct, but it’s very badly expressed. Here’s a much clearer version.

> Suppose that $a=b$. If $a'\in A$, then $a'=ak$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$. But then $a'=ak=bk\in B$, so $A\subseteq B$. Similarly, if $b'\in B$, then $b'=kb$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$, and we have $b'=kb=ka\in A$, so that $B\subseteq A$. Putting the pieces together, we see that $A=B$.

The second part of your argument doesn’t really make sense. If $x\in A=B$, then there are integers $k$ and $\ell$ such that $x=ka$ and $x=\ell b$, but you don’t know that $k=\ell$, so you can’t immediately conclude that $a=b$. Try starting like this:

> Suppose now that $A=B$. Clearly $a\in A$, so $a\in B$, and there is therefore a $k\in\Bbb Z$ such that $a=kb$. Similarly, $b\in A$, so there is an $\ell\in\Bbb Z$ such that $b=\ell a$. Then $a=kb=k\ell a$, so $k\ell=1$.

- Bearing in mind that $k$ and $\ell$ are integers, what are the two possible sets of values of $k$ and $\ell$?
- Use the fact that $a,b\in\Bbb N$ to rule out one of those sets of values and conclude that $a=b$.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say things like "all the elements of $A$ are the same elements of $B$", but rather "every element of $A$ is in $B$". Putting that aside, the second part of your proof has a serious error. You can't argue that because the elements of $A$ are of the form $ak$ and the elements of $B$ are of the form $bk$, then $ak = bk$. What you can say is this. Since $a = a \cdot 1$, $a\in A$, so $a\in B$. Therefore $a = bk$ for some integer $k$. Similarly $b\in A$, so $b = am$ for some integer $m$. Hence $a = bk = amk$, which implies $1 = mk$. So $m = \pm 1$ and $k = \pm 1$. We cannot have $a = -b$ since $a$ and $b$ are natural numbers. So $m = k = 1$, and thus $a = b$.

Answer (score 1):

$\ a=b\,\Rightarrow\,a\Bbb Z = b\Bbb Z.\ $ Conversely if $\,a\Bbb Z = b\Bbb Z\,$  they have equal least positive elements $\,a=b.\,$

Comment: It looks very nice. May you explain the last part?

Comment: @Beginner $\ a\,$ is the least positive element of $\,a\Bbb Z,\,$ and $\,b\,$ is for $\,b\Bbb Z.\,$ So $\,a\Bbb Z=b\Bbb Z\,\Rightarrow\, a=b\,$ since equal sets have equal least positive elements (if they have positive elements).